# List of empty string returns non-zero length in python

Tags: python, linux, list

I have a list of strings returned after command execution, split on '\n'.

```
listname = output.decode('utf8').rstrip().split('\n')
```

When I print using `print(listname)`, I get

```
['']
```

Clearly It's a list containing empty string

Because of this I am getting `len(listname)` as 1.

How to remove this empty string

Comment: You're looking for [`splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
filter(None,output.decode('utf8').rstrip().split('\n'))
```

In details:

```
>>> filter(None, ["Ford", "Nissan", ""])
['Ford', 'Nissan']
```

P.S. In python 3+ `filter` returns iterator, so use `list(filter(..))`.

Comment: +1 but I had to use `list(filter(None,...))` again

Comment: @Drt Good point, updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
listname = [item for item in output.decode('utf8').rstrip().split('\n') if item]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output = output.decode('utf8').rstrip()
if output:
    listname = []
else:
    listname = output.split('\n')
```

Comment: +1, although I'd use a conditional: `lst = out.split('\n') if out else []`